# inotify_add_watch relative to O_PATH dirfd

Tags: linux, inotify

I am trying to call [inotify_add_watch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inotify_add_watch.2.html) to watch a file. I would like to specify the file relative to an O_PATH | O_DIRECTORY file descriptor, a la [symlinkat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), [fstatat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html), or [openat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).

Is this possible? It doesn't look like it is. Anyone know of a workaround?

EDIT

The closest thing seems to be the "trick" described at [man 2 open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) under "Rationale for openat". See the answer by user1643723 for an example.

Comment: Have you tried (ab)using procfs? When you want to emulate functionality of XXXat syscalls, it is always a good idea to try out `/proc/self/fd/<dir descriptor>/filename`.

Comment: I get ENOTDIR when I use pass path like /proc/self/fd/6/foo to inotify_add_watch

Comment: There is some sort of error in your code. Either you are closing the directory descriptor too early, or you are not using the correct descriptor in the first place. Please see my answer for the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use symlinks, provided by *procfs* to achieve the functionality of most **at* calls. Open a directory descriptor and use `/proc/self/fd/<dir descriptor>/filename` instead of the full path to *filename*:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int inotify = inotify_init();

    mkdir("tmp", 0777);
    mknod("tmp/foo", 0777 | S_IFREG, 0);

    int dirFd = open("tmp", O_DIRECTORY | O_PATH);

    char buf[40] = { '\0' };

    sprintf(buf, "/proc/self/fd/%d/foo", dirFd);

    int watchd = inotify_add_watch(inotify, buf, IN_MOVE | IN_ATTRIB);

    if (watchd < 0) {
        printf("Failed: %s", strerror(errno));
    } else {
        printf("ok");
    }
}
```

The program above prints "ok" on Linux 4.4.x.

Comment: You haven't used O_PATH. I need to also be able to pass this file descriptor to proper *at syscalls (like fstatat, etc).

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code to use O_PATH. Still works fine for me. Note, that you don't **have** to use O_PATH with *at syscalls — they work just find with normal file descriptors.

Comment: I guess this is the "trick" described at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html under Rationale. Still holding out for proper *at support for inotify.